# Having images change inside a fixed iPhone Picture

Tags: iphone, image

Hi I am developing a website, and was wondering if anyone knew how to get images to change on scroll inside a fixed iPhone picture.  I've made the iPhone transparent inside the area where I want the images to change.  I've also tried setting a container within a container.  I'm just having trouble getting the coding right so that the images and the iPhone image are responsive when you resize the browser.  I've gotten it to work easily in Adobe Muse, but need it to be responsive so that when someone makes the screen smaller the iPhone and images get smaller as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have photoshop, or what iPhone images you are using, but apple supplies stock iPhone psd's here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images. Also, depending on what you mean by changing the images upon scrolling, maybe you want to look in to "parallax scrolling." You can find resources on that here: [Stack Overflow Parallax Scrolling,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470741/creating-an-effect-where-a-background-image-scrolls-at-a-different-rate-to-the-p) and [More Parallax with Source Code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861645/change-image-on-scroll) If you want to show a completely new image on scroll see here: [jQuery Reel.](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) Both of these solutions will require a knowledge of jQuery. You can easily learn jQuery on [Codecademy.](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery) Suggested course time is 3 hours.